# Json count unique values

Tags: python, json

I have this json file:

```
[
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": ": 12,050",
    "name": "Purge Client Events"
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "name": "",
    "sourceUserName": "",
    "deviceAction": ""
  }
]
```

I am looking for a solution in which I can loop over all the file, and count the unique values for `UserID` and return that value printed.

I found different solution but non of them worked for me and I am completely stuck.

So far this is my code, its just a formatter that convert the file into a json format.

After that I tried to check the length of the file and loop over it appending unique elements.

```
import json
to_queue = []
def structure_json():
    with open("file.json", "r+") as f:
        old = f.read()
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        # save to the old string after replace
        new = old.replace('}{', '},{')
        f.write(new)
        tmps = '[' + str(new) + ']'
        json_string = json.loads(tmps)
        for key in json_string:
            to_queue.append(key)
        f.close
    with open('update_2.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(json_string, file, indent=2)
        size=len(file["UserID"])
        uniqueNames = [];
        for i in range(0,size,1):
            if(file["UserID"] not in uniqueNames):
                uniqueNames.append(file["UserID"]);
                print(uniqueNames)

structure_json()
print(to_queue)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format.py", line 24, in <module>
    structure_json()
  File "format.py", line 17, in structure_json
    size=len(file["UserID"])
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Please any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much for any help, and if you need any more info just let me know

Comment: Show us what have you tried and did not work for you - [mre].

Comment: Sorry mate, I clicked save too quick. I just updated my Post

Comment: Please, show your code and full traceback. Help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, updated again

Comment: `file["UserID"]` You can't index a file object as it "is not subscriptable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file and load the content. Then you can iterate over list of dicts and crate set of all values for key `userID`. Note, if any missing key it will yield `None` and will affect the count (+1).

```
import json

with open('your_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    users = set(item.get('userID') for item in data)
    print(len(users))
    print(users)
```